# Change Doubles to BigDecimals

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I Have this:

```
double priceMulti = 1.3;
double price = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());

//some if's and else's        

double date = (1980 * 2);
double random = Math.random()*15;
jLabel28.setText(String.valueOf((priceMulti * price * date * random)/price));
double copies = Double.parseDouble(jLabel28.getText());
jLabel33.setText(String.valueOf(copies / price));
```

code, and I want to change the variables of price and copies (whose are doubles) to BigDecimals.
I Know that there are some topics like those, but my code is a bit different.
Solved, thanks!

Comment: And? What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to change doubles to BigDecimals.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific

Comment: Read the javadoc. That's what it's for. And you don't want to change doubles to BigDecimal, but Strings to BigDecimal. If you go through a double, you have already lost precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change Doubles to BigDecimals

Look at the constructor [BigDecimal(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29)

```
    double val = 5.2;
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(val));
    System.out.println(bd);
```

Explore other constructors also of `BigDecimal`.

Comment: ` BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(pri);` I did that, but it says it couldn't find symbol 'BigDecimal' so it looks like there is no BigDecimal :O

Comment: Look at the different constructor of `BigDecimal`

Comment: Import `java.math.BigDecimal`

Comment: Yeah, double price = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText()); parsedDouble, but there is error anyway.

Comment: 5.2 cannot be exactly represented as a double, so `val` has a value that is very close to, but not exactly equal to, 5.2. Subsequent construction of a BigDecimal gets that adjusted value. You need use the BigDecimal constructor that takes a String argument instead.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks a lot. I did not test it.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to avoid is converting your strings to double at any point. Once you do that, the number is rounded to a binary fraction. You can, and should, construct a BigDecimal directly from a String that represents a decimal fraction.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "5.2";
    double d = 5.2;
    BigDecimal fromString = new BigDecimal(s);
    BigDecimal fromDouble = new BigDecimal(d);
    System.out.println("From string: " + fromString);
    System.out.println("From double: " + fromDouble);
  }
}
```

result:

```
From string: 5.2
From double: 5.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

`fromString` contains the exact conversion of "5.2" to a decimal fraction, ready to do arithmetic. fromDouble has first been rounded to a number that can be exactly represented as a binary fraction. It is very, very close to 5.2, but slightly different.

To construct a BigDecimal representing a compile-time constant, you still need to use the String argument constructor: `new BigDecimal("5.2")` not `new BigDecimal(5.2)`.